# build.gradle: Copy directory before build

Tags: android, java-native-interface, build.gradle

In my android application I use JNI to work with some C++ library sources.
These sources must be copied from own repository (`".../Connection/Connection"`) into `"src/main/jni/CoreLib/"`

The problem is that I need to re-create `"src/main/jni/CoreLib/"` directory each build to delete unused files. 
I also have a cpp file in `"jni"` folder, which is referencing already deleted file from `"CoreLib"` directory, which gives me an error because of his include:

```
#include "CoreLib/EventDispatcher.h" // "src/main/jni/MyCustomCppFile.cpp
```

I assume that compiler checks includes before my script is executed.
The question is: How can I recreate and copy all cpp sources into my `"CoreLib"` directory **before** any kind of compilation/linking validations? Or is there another workaround to get rid of this error?

Here's some of my `build.gradle` file:

```
task deleteCoreLibDir(type: Delete) {
    println('Deleting CoreLib dir')
    delete 'src/main/jni/CoreLib'
}

task createCoreLibDir {
    File f = new File('src/main/jni/CoreLib/');
    f.mkdirs();
    if (f.exists()) {
        println('Re-created CoreLib dir')
    } else {
        println('!!!! CoreLib dir was not created')
    }
}

task copyConnectionFiles(type: Copy) {
    println('Copying files from Core library to current project')
    File thisProj = file('src');
    File connectionDir = thisProj.parentFile.parentFile.parentFile.parentFile;
    File f = new File(connectionDir, 'Connection/Connection'); // library folder

    from f.absolutePath
    into 'src/main/jni/CoreLib/'
    include('**/*')
}

afterEvaluate {
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.javaCompiler.dependsOn(deleteCoreLibDir)
        variant.javaCompiler.dependsOn(createCoreLibDir)
        variant.javaCompiler.dependsOn(copyConnectionFiles)
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a wrong question to ask. Why not learn how to compile your CPP files without copying them at all?

Comment: That is wrong with this question? Cpp files are compiled without any trouble, i have completely working library. The problem is with copying files before compiling starts (as prebuild event). And copying is a must, as it is another project, developed by someone else. Please explain yourself

Comment: If you want to get the sources from elsewhere (e.g. GIT server), it's OK, but we don't copy files for every compilation: `make` is clever enough to recompile only sources that change; it you always copy everything, you break this behavior.